# Button not always clicking within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this ng-repeat:

```
<div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller='two_way_control'>
    <div ng-repeat="data in ids | orderBy:'amount'">
        <div class="row">
            <!--<div class="col s12 m6">-->
            <center>
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                        <div class="card-content white-text">
                            <p>{{data.amount}} coin wager with {{data.posted_nickname}}
                            <button ng-click="joinflip(data.id)" class="right waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">games</i>Play</button>                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>           
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The button doesn't ALWAYS trigger the function because as the user is moused over it, it's constantly refreshing, thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Not really there's a lot of layers to what I'm doing, the issue is that the button keeps refreshing because of the ng-repeat and that is messing up the user clicking it.

Comment: Well, the above code looks fine. How can we suppose to help you?

Comment: I thought that this must be an issue that happens a lot, so you don't know a fix?

Comment: Try clicking on the <i class="material-icons left">games</i> specifically to see if this is when it doesn't fire.

Comment: Is it within form tag? Then add `type="button"` to the button tag.

Comment: Removing the <i> seems to have fixed it, thanks!